# Read multiple console lines of input & store them in java

Tags: java, io

I'm currently working on a program that reads multiple lines of input from the console, each line is stored in an ArrayList. I have it somewhat working except it only stores every second value, I've tried for a while to figure out what's causing it with no luck. I'd appreciate any help. The code and output are below.

```
System.out.println("\nPlease enter your input: ");
while(input.hasNextLine() && input.nextLine().isEmpty() == false) {
     newLine = input.nextLine();
     System.out.println("new line is: " + newLine);
     inputStrings.add(newLine);
}
System.out.println("input is: " + inputStrings);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Please enter your input:
test1
test2
new line is: test2
test3
test4
new line is: test4
input is: [test2, test4]
```

output should instead be: [test1, test2, test3, test4]

Answer (score 1):

Because you used input.nextLine() twice inside the while loop, which is causing every second value to be skipped. You should only call input.nextLine() once inside the loop and store the value in a variable for further processing.

Try updating your code to the following:

```
while(input.hasNextLine())
{
    newLine = input.nextLine();
    if(newLine.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("new line is: " + newLine);
    inputStrings.add(newLine);
}
```